# What are my photography rights with this client?

Tags: photographers-rights

I’m currently working contract-based with one of direct sales companies. Basically I’m providing 200 lifestyle product images for them each month while being freelance. Mostly they use my pictures for social media, website and internally.

But I noticed one thing. 
I saw some of this company distributors started using my pictures to promote their own sales, I even spotted a couple of websites build fully on my pictures.

What are my rights here? Even with full global buy out?
I mean some of these distributors are making some good money out there using my work which I’m providing to the company, not to them. But company obviously is relying on these distributors.
Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not the right forum, should perhaps be moved to legal.SE. That being said, I don’t think you have any rights over the pictures if you sold them to your client.

Comment: Also: It depends on your contract terms, country, and so on: In my country, you cannot _ever_ lose your copyright (i.e. the photo is forever the photographer's intellectual property), though you can grant (almost) unlimited rights of usage to your clients. I don't know for certain, but I am fairly sure that in other countries, you _can_ lose/sell your copyright.

Comment: Read your contract. Contact a lawyer.

Comment: As @osullic says - the company's reproduction and resale rights are probably spelled out in your contract. If they're not, then your rights in this instance will be subject to your local laws and you may or may not have a tough time recouping damages. In any case, you need to contact a lawyer. In my experience, you'll pay for an hour of their time for them to review your contract and provide advice. Search for Intellectual Property or Copyright lawyers in your area.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's highly speculative. We don't know the jurisdiction or contractual obligations and even if all of that info were posted, the best advice is still: talk to a lawyer.

Comment: "full global buy out" = your client owns the copyrights to the images? ... If so, copyright violations are not your problem anymore.  If you attempt to go after violations, you could be sued for fraud, or some such.  Also, if you attempt to use the images yourself, you could be sued for copyright infringement.  Notify the client of your observations and leave it at that.